# Strange NPE with io.circe.Decoder

Tags: scala, circe

I have 2 variables declared as follows,

```
 implicit val decodeURL: Decoder[URL] = Decoder.decodeString.emapTry(s => Try(new URL(s)))     // #1

 implicit val decodeCompleted = Decoder[List[URL]].prepare(_.downField("completed")) // #2
```

Both lines compile and run.

However, if I annotate #2 with type i.e. `implicit val decodeCompleted: Decoder[List[URL]] = Decoder[List[URL]].prepare(_.downField("completed"))`. It compiles and #2 will throw `NullPointerException` (NPE) during runtime.

How could this happen? I don't know if this is Circe or just plain Scala issue. Why #2 is different from #1? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are supposed to use implicits with annotation always.

Now, when you use them when they are not annotated you get into some sort on undefined/invalid behavior zone. That is why with unannotated happens sth like this:

- I want to use `Decoder[List[URL]]`
- there is no (annotated) `Decoder[List[URL]]` implicit in the scope
- let's derive it normally (no need for `generic.auto._` because the definition for that is in a companion object)
- once derived you call on it .prepare(_.downField("completed"))
- the final result is of type `Decoder[List[URL]]`, so that is inferred type of `decodeCompleted`

Now, what happens if you annotate?

- I want to use `Decoder[List[URL]]`
- there is `decodeCompleted` declared as something that fulfills that definition
- let use `decodeCompleted` value
- but `decodeCompleted` wasn't initialized! in fact we are initializing it right now!
- as a result you end up with `decodeCompleted = null`

This is virtually equal to:

```scala
val decodeCompleted = decodeCompleted
```

except that the layer of indirection get's in the way of discovering the absurdity of this by compiler. (If you replaced `val` with `def` you would end up with an infinite recursion and stack overflow):

```scala
@ implicit val s: String = implicitly[String] 
s: String = null

@ implicit def s: String = implicitly[String] 
defined function s

@ s 
java.lang.StackOverflowError
  ammonite.$sess.cmd1$.s(cmd1.sc:1)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd1$.s(cmd1.sc:1)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd1$.s(cmd1.sc:1)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd1$.s(cmd1.sc:1)
```

**Yup, its messed up by compiler. You did nothing wrong and in a perfect world it would work.**

Scala community mitigates that by distincting:

- auto derivation - when you need implicit somewhere and it is automatically derived without you defining a variable for it
- semiauto derivation - when you derive into a value, and make that value implicit

In the later case, you usually have some utilities like:

```scala
import io.circe.generic.semiauto._

implicit val decodeCompleted: Decoder[List[URL]] = deriveDecoder[List[URL]]
```

It works because it takes `DerivedDecoder[A]` implicit and then it extracts `Decoder[A]` from it, so you never end up with `implicit val a: A = implicitly[A]` scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the problem is that you introduce a recursive `val`, like @MateuszKubuszok explained.

The most straightforward—although slightly ugly—workaround is:

```
implicit val decodeCompleted: Decoder[List[URL]] = {
  val decodeCompleted = null
  Decoder[List[URL]].prepare(_.downField("completed"))
}
```

By shadowing `decodeCompleted` in the right-hand side, implicit search will no longer consider it as a candidate inside that code block, because it can no longer be referenced.